# Scaling system image in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use "mappin" system image from SF Symbols with a circular background. No matter what width, height or padding I use, the image always looks squished. The original image is thin and tall and when I try to use it, the image looks fat and squished.

I tried setting same value for width and height, setting height greater than width, but nothing seems to show original image. I even tried scaleToFit() instead of scaleToFill() and that didn't help either.

***Code:***

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "mappin")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 8.0, height: 5.0, alignment: .center)
        .padding(5.0)
        .background(Color.green)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .clipShape(Circle())
    TextField("Hello World", text: .constant("Hello")).foregroundColor(Color.black)
}
```

***Output of the above code:***

[image]

***mappin screenshot from SF Symbols:***

[image]

What can I do to make the icon look thinner and taller?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried potentially adding   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)? Sorry not by computer right now, but first guess would be this.

Comment: Tried replacing scaleToFill with aspectRatio and also tried aspectRatio with scaledToFill/scaledToFit.. gives same result.

Comment: Your code above seem normal to me, but if you can't adjust width or hight I think the problem isn't from the block of code you show above, does you have any other view that wrap the block of code above? if so I think it's might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a particular size (which won’t scale with the user’s text settings), you can simply use the version of the mappin SF Symbol with a filled circle. This will scale proportionally with the text according to the user’s settings:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(.green)
    TextField("Hello World", text: .constant("Hello")).foregroundColor(Color.black)
}
```

The symbol will appear at a size Apple thinks is a good match for the text. You can use `.imageScale` to choose small, medium (default) or large sizes for some control. Alternatively, setting a different font text style other than the default body can be used to adjust the size somewhat and still have it scale correctly with the user’s text size settings.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I didn't noticed there was a mappin fill icon already. With my code it was probably the clip shape that was squishing the icon.